# UIRefreshControl with Table View Cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[refresh_screenie_image_here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkG0U.png)

I have a Table View Controller with 2 reusable cells, named as "firstCell", "SecondCell". FirstCell contains my TextField and Post button. SecondCell contains just TextView (with not editable and selectable enabled). Data is retrieve from Firebase. When I post new feed/message, the TextView doesn't update with my code, the 'RefreshControl'. Might I be missing anything here ?

```
@IBAction func refreshControl(_ sender: UIRefreshControl) {
    refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

---

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase

class SecondCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var postTextView: UITextView!

    var dataRef:DatabaseReference?
    var postStr = ""

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

        dataRef = Database.database().reference()

        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid

        if let user = user {
            dataRef?.child("Users/\(userID)/Posts/").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                for snap in snapshot.children {
                    let userSnap = snap as! DataSnapshot
                    let userDict = userSnap.value as! [String:AnyObject]
                    let getPost = userDict["Posts"] as! String
                        self.postStr += "\(getPost) \n"
                            print(getPost)
                        self.postTextView.text = self.postStr
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

---

---

//See edited #post2 here...

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "firstCell", for: indexPath)
                return cell

        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "secondCell", for: indexPath)
                return cell
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you get you data from? Can you post some more code?

Comment: Updated my section of code. The codes falls within UITableViewCell named "SecondCell"

Comment: Ok, what do you want to use UIRefreshControl for? I got from the question that you want to update TextView after posting new message from firstCell

Comment: you must move the responsability to access data and send the update data to cell to the viewcontroller. your tableview can be recicled and all that data could be lost, so you need a reference to both cell to sned the update from one to another, so that all must be in the viewcontroller

Comment: @TiranUt meaning ? You are able to see the new data update at “SecondCell” ?

Comment: @kjoe I have set the refresh and table view reload data at Table View Controller Level, is this what you meant ?

Comment: No the function to retrieve the data and the function to update the data should be in tableViewController and then get reference to cell to update value

Comment: I need to reference my 'SecondCell' at the 2nd (which is index.row == 1) row of my tableVIew ? (See my edited #post2)

Comment: @WengieLoh your question is not clear, what do you expect and what happened instead, please clearly state these in your question.

Comment: The screenshot I attached previously shows existing data in Firebase. New data that is not being written to Firebase it’s shown but on my textView at Cell 2 doesn’t reflect the new data. My UIButton is doing the job of written data to Firebase upon submitting

Comment: is not being shown*

Comment: Self resolved. Thanks All.

Answer (score 0):

This question is self resolved by the owner @wengie